# Play store rejecting app updates because it violates family policy

Tags: google-play, admob

I uploaded a new update to my app on the google play store but for reasons i dont understand it keeps rejecting the update stating that the adverts go against the policy outlined in the family policy.

I have search quite a bit and found that i needed to go onto the ADMOB website and set the content rating to "G".  After that i went to the "sensitive categories" and i eventually disabled all of them after the 3rd attempt.  I found a post on stack overflow that states you need to specify the content rating before you initialize ADMOB in your code.

```
RequestConfiguration requestConfiguration = MobileAds.getRequestConfiguration()
            .toBuilder()
            .setMaxAdContentRating(MAX_AD_CONTENT_RATING_G)
            .build();
```

//*** Digital content labels end ***//

```
    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {

                }
            });
```

It still rejects my app saying the the app contains inappropriate adverts.  It doesn't even specifiy if it is an automated check looking for something specific.  Is there any other changes to their system that requires anything extra?

EDIT : I looked at the email a bit closer and i noticed the complaint is always against version code 5(the one on the play store) where i am now at 8 after trying to fix the issue.  I though perhaps i need to disable the version code 5 so it will just move on and accept the new version but apparently that isn't possible.